# JQuery Calculation Button Scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on a project that calculates your GPA for my local school. It use to work like the following. You would enter your grades and it would calculate it on the fly (as you input the data). I recently added a calculation button that prevented the GPA to be displayed until the calculation button is pressed. The issue is, when the calculation button is pressed another slot to enter more grades is shown. I believe this is occurring because the following code is also being called.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
});
```

My goal is when the calculation button is pressed it ONLY display the GPA result, not another input section like it is currently doing. Also I want to keep the functionality of the Add Class button which adds the input section.

```js
var $oBox = $('.outer-box');
var $gpa = $('#gpa');
var $result = $('.result').hide();

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
});

$oBox.on('keyup', '.credits', function() {
  $gpa.text(getTotal());
});

$oBox.on("change", ".grade-select", function() {
 
});

function getTotal() {
  var gradeTotal = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  $(".credits").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!isNaN($this.val()) && !isNaN($this.parent().find('.grade-select').val())) {
      sum += parseFloat($this.val() || 0) * parseFloat($this.parent().find('.grade-select').val() || 0);
      gradeTotal += parseFloat($this.val() || 0)
    }
  });
  return (sum / gradeTotal).toFixed(2);
}

$("#Calculate").on("click", function() {
 $gpa.text(getTotal());
  $result.is(":hidden") && $result.show();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 'slow');
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #A00000;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer-box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: true;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
.block {
  margin: 5px;
}
.class {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.credits {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.grade-select {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.btn {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.result {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
}
#gpa {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='outer-box'>
  <div class='inner-box'>
    <form class='block'>
      <input type="text" class='class' placeholder="Class">
      </br>
      <select class='credits'>
        <option value="">Credits</option>
        <option value="0.5">Half Year</option>
        <option value="1">Full Year</option>
      </select>
      </br>
      <select class='grade-select'>
        <option value="">Grade</option>
        <option value="4.6">A+</option>
        <option value="4.0">A</option>
        <option value="3.6">B+</option>
        <option value="3.0">B</option>
        <option value="2.6">C+</option>
        <option value="2.0">C</option>
        <option value="1.0">D</option>
        <option value="0.0">F</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='btn btn-default'>Add Class</div>
  </br>
  <button id="Calculate" class='btn btn-default' >Calculate</button>
  <div class='result'>
    <h3 id="gpa">GPA</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes just need to comment following code and it will not insert another block and only display result as per your goal.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  //$('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
});
```

OR for add class button to be working need to change code as bellow

```
<div id='btnAddClass' class='btn btn-default'>Add Class</div>

 $('#btnAddClass').click(function() {
      $('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
    });
```

Comment: Because if I replace that segment it will prevent the Add Class button from working.

Comment: At existing code just comment out code section as I do above.

Comment: I have checked in code snippet using comment it and it working as you expected